# Libgdx using "Normal Map" Texture for shader in 3D

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, shader, normals

After reading [this Tutorial](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson6) about GLSL and how to use "Normal Mapping" to  create such great dynamic `Texture`s out of a simple stonewall, i am really impressed by the power of `Shader`s.
As i am stil new to `Shader`s and 3D at all, i am wondering how to apply this kind of `Shader` to my wip 3D game. So i was looking for some more tutorials and i have found [this](http://www.upvector.com/?section=Tutorials&subsection=Intro%20to%20Shaders), which gave me some more knowledge about `Shader`s and their logic. But i am stil not sure if i really understood it so i ask here.
What i want to do: I have some basic `Wall`s, made of simple, textured cubes. The `Texture`s are more or less the same as in the first Tutorial i linked to. I have the `Normal Map` of this `Texture`, also like in the Tutorial, and i want to add the same effect to those `Texture`s, but as i said it is 3D.
So as much as i understood i don't have to change anything, but the `Normal Map`. I have to know the face of the block, on which the `Texture` is and <s>multiply its normal by the Faces normal (for example Vector3(-1, 0, 0) for left Face)</s> rotate it (for example arround the `Y-Axis` by 90° for right `Face`). Is this assumption right or am i on the wrong track?
And if i am right, instead of using the `Normal Map Texture`, is there also a way to get the normal of every "pixel" (point) of an imported g3db `Model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what ever you want as input for your shaders, but texure is the common input for per fragment modifications.

[Uniform Buffer vs Texture Performances considerations](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/01/uniform-buffers-vs-texture-buffers/)

The classic normal mapping technique with tangent space informations (per pixel coordinate system) could be overridden by other techniques (ex: bump map) and even your own implementation. Take care that the tangent vectors (Tangent,Binormal,Normal) used for normal or bump mapping have to be precalculated and added to your vertex attributes. You can use a dirty trick to compute them in vertex shader, but that's leed to some glitch.

Your example use only a fragment shader so you are right that something is missing to have it working in a 3d scene.

For this to work in 3d, you need to implement a vertex shader that will take care of per vertex normal ([here is a implementation](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/bump_mapping_p4.php)) :

```
 [Vertex_Shader]

varying vec3 lightVec; 
varying vec3 eyeVec;
varying vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 vTangent; 


void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    texCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;

    vec3 n = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    vec3 t = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vTangent);
    vec3 b = cross(n, t);

    vec3 vVertex = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
    vec3 tmpVec = gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vVertex;

    lightVec.x = dot(tmpVec, t);
    lightVec.y = dot(tmpVec, b);
    lightVec.z = dot(tmpVec, n);

    tmpVec = -vVertex;
    eyeVec.x = dot(tmpVec, t);
    eyeVec.y = dot(tmpVec, b);
    eyeVec.z = dot(tmpVec, n);
}

[Pixel_Shader]

varying vec3 lightVec;
varying vec3 eyeVec;
varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform float invRadius;

void main (void)
{
    float distSqr = dot(lightVec, lightVec);
    float att = clamp(1.0 - invRadius * sqrt(distSqr), 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 lVec = lightVec * inversesqrt(distSqr);

    vec3 vVec = normalize(eyeVec);

    vec4 base = texture2D(colorMap, texCoord);

    vec3 bump = normalize( texture2D(normalMap, texCoord).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);

    vec4 vAmbient = gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;

    float diffuse = max( dot(lVec, bump), 0.0 );

    vec4 vDiffuse = gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * 
                    diffuse;    

    float specular = pow(clamp(dot(reflect(-lVec, bump), vVec), 0.0, 1.0), 
                     gl_FrontMaterial.shininess );

    vec4 vSpecular = gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * 
                     specular;  

    gl_FragColor = ( vAmbient*base + 
                     vDiffuse*base + 
                     vSpecular) * att;
}
```

You may use a dirty trick to get tangent if you don't add them to your vertex attributes

```
vec3 c1 = cross( gl_Normal, vec3( 0, 0, 1 ) );
vec3 c2 = cross( gl_Normal, vec3( 0, 1, 0 ) );

if( length( c1 ) > length( c2 ) ) tangent = normalize( c1 );
else tangent = normalize( c2 );
```

Comment: You can see that in the first tutorial. I have the given `Texture` (the stonewall) and its normal map and i want to create the dynamic lit `Texture`. The differenc is, that the `Texture` is not always facing in the same direction, as it would be the case in 2D. For this i wanted to know if it is enough to rotate the normal Vector arround the `Y-Axis` by 90, 180, 270° to create the `Left Face`, `Back Face` and `Right Face`?

Comment: not sur i understand what you call lit texture. normals in the normal map image are per pixel coordinate, so model orientation is not important. Normals of your vertices are processed with ModelProjection matrice (thru fixed pipeline or your own one) so, model orientation implies no changes in defined normals

Comment: I have this "stonewall" Texture and a "flashlight", with the same direction as my camera. I want to create the effect in the link (the picture at the right side of the stonewall, the lit stonewall). For this i need the normals, to say which parts are lit and which not. The normal map texture is always the same, but the normals change, if they are at another face of my block model. To explain that:
The `Z-Axis` of the normal (in the tutorial the blue channel) is facing toward the `Z-axis`, but if it is on the left face of a block, it would face the negative `X-Axis`

Comment: to compute your light vector in a 3d scene, you need to implement it's calculation in the vertex shader where N = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal); which is your vertex normal. I think that's what is missing in that example.

Comment: and the `gl_NormalMatrix` would be what?

Comment: It's a built in attribute, correctely setted for vertex normal transformation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50103/discussion-between-springrbua-and-j-p)